# Collect CSS/JS Resources in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I would like to collect all css/js resources in a controller.

This would result in one HTTP Request for each resource.

Example:

```
package my.package;

// [...imports...]

@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/res" )
public class ResourcesController
{
  @RequestMapping( value = "/style.css", headers = "content-type=text/css" )
  // [...] collect all css files from /WEB-INF/css/**

  @RequestMapping( value = "/scripts.js", headers = "content-type=text/javascript" )
  // [...] collect all js files from /WEB-INF/js/**
}
```

I already have an DispatcherServlet which uses Apache Tiles, so I guess i need to make a new servlet?!

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>?org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet?</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/res/*.css</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/res/*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is class org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet correct?

What I have to put in my resources-servlet.xml then? This?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" />

  <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

</beans>
```

And how my mapping methods should look like in the controller?
Any example code would be very useful. Can't find anything on the internet...

Comment: Not entirely sure why you would want to do this. And given the fact that you can't find any resources about it suggests that few people do.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about the Spring part, but I can at least tell that your URL pattern is wrong. The `*` can only be the first of the last character. E.g. `/res/*` or `*.js`.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already have an DispatcherServlet which uses Apache Tiles, so I guess I need to make a new servlet?!

No -- you should have only the DispatcherServlet. -- Every Spring Controller is handled by this servlet.

---

But in general it looks strange what you do.

- Spring already have a "tool" that allows to access static ressources `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` See [Spring Reference Chapter 16.14.5 Configuring Serving of Resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

for example

```
   <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"
    mapping="/resources/**" />
```

- But maybe you try something more complex like [Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/)?